# use private to specify access control of a class

Tags: java, class, private, protected

I have been reading Thinking in Java from Bruce Eckel these days, when comes to the Access Control chapter, it says if a java file has two or more classes, except the public one, others can not be `private` (that would make it inaccessible to anyone but the class) or `protected`.

But I have seen a lot of popular java libraries and open source projects did have used private to decorate these kind of classes.

So is it because the book too theoretical or any reason else?

the original text (page 231, forth edition)

> Note that a class can not be private (that would make it inaccessible to anyone but the class) or protected. So you have only two choices for class acess: package acces or public. If you don`t want anyone else to have access to that class, you can make all the constructors private, thereby preventing anyone but you, inside a static member of the class, form creating an object of that class.

Comment: I suspect strongly that you simply misread the book.

Comment: I think CommonsWare is right, anyway private and protected can be used with inner classes(classes inside classes) but can't with classes that aren't within any class

Comment: The book is now quite old; you should expect it to be outdated. There are several innacuracies in that short paragraph when compared to current Java.

Comment: In the 3rd edition of that book there is a footnote marker behind `... or  protected`. Footnote text: *Actually, an inner class can be private or protected, but that’s a special case. These will 
be introduced in Chapter 7*

Answer (score 3):

The statement is only true for top-level (non-nested) classes.  Nested classes may be `private`.  That's because top-level classes have visibility into private nested classes (including the private members of a nested class), and vice versa.  They may also be `protected`, meaning subclasses of the *enclosing* class, even in another package, can reference them.

Note that this isn't unique to Java files that declare more than one top-level class. `private` and `protected` are not allowed on any top-level class declaration.